# WAMP php version is not recognized - composer error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, wamp

I run Laravel 9 on Windows 10.

Everything worked find until installed this package:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-livewire-wizard/v1/introduction

and now I get this error in the browser when trying to browse my site:
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.13. in C:\wamp64\www\highland9.local\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 24

After googling it I check all of these:

php version on Wamp shows 8.1.0

phpinfo() shows 8.1.0

localhost in the browser shows php version 8.1.0

Windows path points to: c:\wamp64\bin\php8.1.0

cmd php -v shows: 8.1.0

In my composer.json file:

it was:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
```

I changed it to:

```
"php":"^8.1.0"
```

and ran composer update

I tried removing the package like this:

composer remove vendor/spatie/laravel-livewire-wizard

It said there's nothing to remove.

I renamed the folder to laravel-livewire-wizardDEL

I removed the line:

"spatie/laravel-livewire-wizard": "^1.1",

from composer.json and ran composer update

Nothing helps, still get this error.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please send output of the command **composer diagnose**

Comment: C:\Users\Name>composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 2.3.10
PHP version: 8.1.0

Comment: PHP binary path: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
cURL version: 7.77.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1l
zip: extension present, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available

Comment: I also tried to remove the php version from the path because Wamp complains about it, that didn't help either.

Comment: I tried adding this to composer.json under config: "platform-check": false ran composer update, composer dump-autoload, php artisan clear:cache but then I got a different error something about a ')' somewhere, and the php version shown on the error page was 8.0.13. It's like laravel or the browser or something totally ignores the php version selected in wamp

Comment: under localhost I see this: 
Your VirtualHost (2)

    localhost
    mysite.local

    FCGI -> PHP 8.0.13

Comment: Ok, managed to update the virtual host php version from wamp/YourVirtualHosts/Virtual Host management.

Comment: Best wishes for you.

Comment: @EHF Shahab, thank you so much for trying to help.

Comment: What's the output of `composer check-platform-reqs` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've overwritten the PHP version under the `platform` key in your project's local `composer.json` or the global `~/.composer/composer.json`.

Look for the following section:

```
{
  "platform": {
    "php": "8.0.13"
}
```

See: Documentation - Config - [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform)

Use the following commands to dump the current value:

```
composer config platform
composer config --global platform
```